# Run chef-client periodically: error in command line

Tags: chef-infra, devops

I'm trying to follow the Chef Tutorial (rif. https://learn.chef.io).

I'm using CentOS 7 for my workstation environment and also for my destination node.

They are generated using Vagrant box as suggested by the tutorial.

I'm using Chef server hosted by Chef (rif. https://manage.chef.io/login).

Al works fine and I'm able to deploy cookbooks from my workstation to my destination node uploading cookbooks on Chef Server.

Now I'm trying to tun chef-client periodically and I'm defined a role `web` as suggested by the tutorial here https://learn.chef.io/modules/manage-a-node-chef-server/rhel/hosted/run-chef-client-periodically#/.

I'm trying to run the `chef-client` with this command from command line

```
 $ knife ssh 'role:web' 'sudo chef-client' --ssh-user root --ssh-password 'vagrant' --attribute 192.168.44.10
```

where the attribute value is my destination node IP address, and user and password are by default for my Vagrant environments

What I obtain is the following

```
[vagrant@localhost roles]$ knife ssh 'role:web' 'sudo chef-client' --ssh-user root --ssh-password 'vagrant' --attribute 192.168.44.10
localhost [2018-08-17T09:25:45+00:00] WARN: *****************************************
localhost [2018-08-17T09:25:45+00:00] WARN: Did not find config file: /etc/chef/client.rb, using command line options.
localhost [2018-08-17T09:25:45+00:00] WARN: *****************************************
localhost Starting Chef Client, version 14.2.0
localhost
localhost Running handlers:
localhost [2018-08-17T09:25:56+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
localhost Running handlers complete
localhost [2018-08-17T09:25:56+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
localhost Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 10 seconds
localhost [2018-08-17T09:25:56+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
localhost [2018-08-17T09:25:56+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
localhost [2018-08-17T09:25:56+00:00] FATAL: Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /etc/chef/chef_guid
```

The stacktrace content is the following:

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /etc/chef/chef_guid
/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/chef-14.2.0/lib/chef/client.rb:1012:in `initialize'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/chef-14.2.0/lib/chef/client.rb:1012:in `open'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/chef-14.2.0/lib/chef/client.rb:1012:in `generate_guid'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/chef-14.2.0/lib/chef/client.rb:262:in `run'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/chef-14.2.0/lib/chef/application.rb:303:in `run_with_graceful_exit_option'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/chef-14.2.0/lib/chef/application.rb:279:in `block in run_chef_client'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/chef-14.2.0/lib/chef/local_mode.rb:44:in `with_server_connectivity'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/chef-14.2.0/lib/chef/application.rb:261:in `run_chef_client'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/chef-14.2.0/lib/chef/application/client.rb:441:in `run_application'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/chef-14.2.0/lib/chef/application.rb:66:in `run'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/chef-14.2.0/bin/chef-client:26:in `<top (required)>'
/bin/chef-client:272:in `load'
/bin/chef-client:272:in `<main>'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you run through the steps to bootstrap the node first? (https://learn.chef.io/modules/manage-a-node-chef-server/rhel/hosted/bootstrap-your-node)

Comment: yes and it works .... here you're the command I've used in that case ... `knife bootstrap 192.168.44.10 --ssh-user root --ssh-password 'vagrant' --use-sudo-password --node-name chef_node_1 --run-list 'recipe[learn_chef_httpd]`

Comment: It seems that it try to execute on my workstation (`/etc/chef` does not exist ....), and not on the destination node where `chef-client` exist and also `/etc/chef/client.rb`

Comment: What's in the stacktrace file?

Comment: I've updated my original question with the content of `/var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out` ...

Comment: That sounds a lot like `/etc/chef` doesn't exist on your target node. Are you 100% certain it exists?

Comment: yes, I've verified and on my target node and `/etc/chef` exist, and its content is:  `chef_guid, client.pem, client.rb, first-boot.json ` (note: my node bootstrap, following the tutorial was ok ... )